# Using jOOQ query to return all records from CSV

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I am trying to create an endpoint that would return a csv file for download. So far I had an endpoint that returned json in the response, and I want to simply change json to csv, but do it without pagination as in the case of json (because it's there).

```
override fun find(query: TransactionQuery): org.springframework.data.domain.Page<List<TransactionDetails>> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

Comment: Take a look at fetchStream https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchStream(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you mean is that you want to avoid the type of [dynamic SQL with jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), where you'd either include or exclude a `LIMIT` clause in your query, or write the query twice, depending on the export mode.

You can always just pass a [`DSL::noField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/no-field/) to the `LIMIT` clause to make the call to `.limit()` a no-op:

```java
.limit(isCsv
  ? noField(SQLDataType.INTEGER)
  : (page.number - 1) * page.size, page.size + 1)
```

Passing such conditional arguments to the jOOQ DSL is part of [jOOQ's dynamic SQL support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/), knowing that *every* jOOQ query is a dynamic SQL query, even if it looks like a static query thanks to the DSL's similarity to actual SQL.

Note that [jOOQ also supports exporting data in CSV format](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-csv/), so perhaps you can use that as well (it's not clear to me from your question if that's part of your question).